# Search data on click event of button using smart table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, smart-table

I am very new to the smart table. I have gone through its documentation on [Smart Table](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/).
But the I haven't found how to bind data on click event in smart table?
Code is very big but I am trying to post it here.

```html
<div class="table-scroll-x" st-table="backlinksData" st-safe-src="backlinks" st-set-filter="myStrictFilter">
  <div class="crawlhealthshowcontent">
    <div class="crawlhealthshowcontent-right">
      <input type="text" class="crserachinput" placeholder="My URL" st-search="{{TargetUrl}}" />
      <a class="bluebtn">Search</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="table-header clearfix">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6_5">
        <div st-sort="SourceUrl" st-skip-natural="true">
          Page URL
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div st-sort="SourceAnchor" st-skip-natural="true">
          Anchor Text
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <div st-sort="ExternalLinksCount" st-skip-natural="true">
          External<br />Links
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <div st-sort="InternalLinksCount" st-skip-natural="true">
          Internal<br />Links
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <div st-sort="IsFollow" st-skip-natural="true">
          Type
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-body clearfix">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="backlink in backlinksData" ng-if="backlinks.length > 0">
      <div class="col-sm-6_5">
        <div class="pos-rel">
          <span class="display-inline wrapWord" tool-tip="{{ backlink.SourceUrl }}"><b>Backlink source:</b> <a target="_blank" href="{{backlink.SourceUrl}}">{{ backlink.SourceUrl }}</a></span><br />
          <span class="display-inline wrapWord" tool-tip="{{ backlink.SourceTitle }}"><b>Link description:</b> {{ backlink.SourceTitle }}</span> <br />
          <span class="display-inline wrapWord" tool-tip="{{ backlink.TargetUrl }}"><b>My URL:</b> <a target="_blank" href="{{backlink.TargetUrl}}">{{ backlink.TargetUrl }}</a></span><br />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="pos-rel">
          {{ backlink.SourceAnchor }}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <div>
          {{ backlink.ExternalLinksCount }}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <div>
          {{ backlink.InternalLinksCount }}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <div ng-if="!backlink.IsFollow">
          No Follow
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" ng-if="backlinks.length == 0">
      No backlinks exists for selected location.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pos-rel" st-pagination="" st-displayed-pages="10" st-template="Home/PaginationCustom"></div>
</div>
```

and my js code is here.

```js
module.controller('backlinksController', [
  '$scope','$filter', 'mcatSharedDataService', 'globalVariables', 'backlinksService',
  function ($scope,$filter, mcatSharedDataService, globalVariables, backlinksService) {

    $scope.dataExistsValues = globalVariables.dataExistsValues;

    var initialize = function () {
      $scope.backlinks = undefined;
      $scope.sortOrderAsc = true;
      $scope.sortColumnIndex = 0;

    };

    initialize();

    $scope.itemsByPage = 5;

    var updateTableStartPage = function () {
      // clear table before loading
      $scope.backlinks = [];
      // end clear table before loading

      updateTableData();
    };

    var updateTableData = function () {

      var property = mcatSharedDataService.PropertyDetails();
      if (property == undefined || property.Primary == null || property.Primary == undefined || property.Primary.PropertyId <= 0) {
        return;
      }
      var params = {
        PropertyId: property.Primary.PropertyId
      };

      var backLinksDataPromise = backlinksService.getBackLinksData($scope, params);

      $scope.Loading = backLinksDataPromise;
    };

    mcatSharedDataService.subscribeCustomerLocationsChanged($scope, updateTableStartPage);
  }
]);
module.filter('myStrictFilter', function ($filter) {
  return function (input, predicate) {
    return $filter('filter')(input, predicate, true);
  }
});
```

But It is working fine with the direct search on textbox.
but according to the requirement I have to perform it on button click.
Your suggestions and help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for a specific row by making some simple tweaks.

1. add a filter to the `ng-repeat`, and filter it by a model that you will insert on the button click, like so: `<tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection | filter: searchQuery">`
2. in your view, add that model (using `ng-model`) to an input tag and define it in your controller
3. then pass the value to the filter when you click the search button

[here's a plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/gu59Vu?p=preview) that demonstrates this

you can use `filter:searchQuery:true` for strict search

**EDIT:**

OK, so OP's big problem was that the filtered values wouldn't show properly when paginated, the filter query is taken from an input box rather then using the de-facto `st-search` plug-in, So I referred to an already [existing issue in github](https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table/issues/220) ([similar](https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table/issues/391)), I've pulled out this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/dpmSdEaL2Xuyb1BWLbVh?p=preview) and [modified it slightly](http://plnkr.co/edit/RolMwXiXM5gkpEcYrQhb?p=preview) to fit the questioned use case.

Comment: Yes you are right but when we have lots of records and pagination would be there then this won't work. I tried this solution before but with pagination it is not working please check. Thanks for your impromptu reply

Comment: how would that not work? you aren't really making a search, rather you query your backend, get all records, filter them, and show only those that match your pattern. after you click the search button, grab all those that were "filtered" and paginate those (while your original data is in `st-safe-src`)

Comment: I grab data from back end only at first time then I don't make call to database. I am using paging and sorting functionality provided by smart table it self.

Comment: gotcha, you mean something like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/RolMwXiXM5gkpEcYrQhb?p=preview

Comment: Yes that's amazing..!! Thank you very much :)